# How to read from functional mailbox in ASP.NET with application on server

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, outlook

I'm developing an application that will have about 15 users. Each user will have to programmatically be able to click a button and read the emails in their shared functional mailbox (which is called **Media processing**).

When I test my code locally, everything works fine. But now that I published it to the server, it's not working anymore (because it's probably looking in the mailbox on the server instead of on the users' mailbox.

In my web.config:

```
<add key="asFuncMailboxInbox" value="Media Processing" />
<add key="asFuncMailboxOutbox" value="902. Outbox" />
```

This is my method to process the emails:

```
string inboxName = WebConfigurationManager.AppSettings["asFuncMailboxInbox"];
string outboxName = WebConfigurationManager.AppSettings["asFuncMailboxOutbox"];

try
{
    OutlookApp myApp = new OutlookApp();
    OutlookNameSpace mapiNameSpace = myApp.GetNamespace("MAPI");
    MapiFolder myInbox = mapiNameSpace.GetDefaultFolder(Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.OlDefaultFolders.olFolderInbox);
    MapiFolder mySubFolder = myInbox.Folders[inboxName];
    MapiFolder destinationFolder = myInbox.Folders[outboxName];

    var myItems = mySubFolder.Items;
    myItems.Sort("[ReceivedTime]", true);

    count = 0;

    if (myItems.Count > 0)
    {
        totalCount = myItems.Count;
        for (var i = myItems.Count; i > 0; i--)
        {
            var itemObject = myItems[i] as MailItem;
            if (itemObject != null)
            {
                var isOk = NewBankFactoryHelper.IsMessageCorrectlyConstructed(itemObject.Body);

                if (isOk)
                {
                    StoreNewBankRequestEmailData(itemObject);
                    itemObject.Move(destinationFolder);
                    count++;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
catch (System.Exception e)
{
    hasError = true;
    errorMessage = e.ToString();
}
finally
{
    template = string.Format(CommonResources.Label_RequestsDownloadSuccess, count, totalCount);

    if (count < totalCount)
    {
        template += CommonResources.Label_EmailIncorrectFormat;
    }
    if (hasError)
    {
        template += string.Format(CommonResources.Label_RequestDownloadFailed, errorMessage);
    }
}
```

Comment: You've answered your own question, that it's looking locally on the server. It's a bad idea to use Interop on a server, Microsoft advise not to do so. You should be using something like Exchange Web Services (EWS) instead.

Comment: @Equalsk do you think it's possible to access the mailbox of the users directly on their computer, or do you think I need to access their mailbox by having Outlook installed on the server as well and have the functional mailbox on there as well?

Comment: I doubt the first would work, the second would work but it is not the recommended way. It's an "easy" fix, but not the "right" fix.

Answer (score 0):

**Microsoft does not currently recommend, and does not support, Automation of Microsoft Office applications from any unattended, non-interactive client application or component (including ASP, ASP.NET, DCOM, and NT Services), because Office may exhibit unstable behavior and/or deadlock when Office is run in this environment.**

If you are building a solution that runs in a server-side context, you should try to use components that have been made safe for unattended execution. Or, you should try to find alternatives that allow at least part of the code to run client-side. If you use an Office application from a server-side solution, the application will lack many of the necessary capabilities to run successfully. Additionally, you will be taking risks with the stability of your overall solution. Read more about that in the [Considerations for server-side Automation of Office](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/257757) article.

If you deal with Exchange mailboxes only you may consider using EWS, see [EWS Managed API, EWS, and web services in Exchange](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dd877012%28v=exchg.150%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) for more information. Also you may consider using any third-party components which don't require Outlook installed on the machine. Or just use a low-level API - Extended MAPI.